# How do I "smooth" out odd stretches and rotations on my human mesh?

Tags: mesh, edges, sculpting

I made a human prototype mesh and get these odd stretches across the facial region. I'm not sure if this is a vertex issue in Edit mode or needs to be worked on in Sculpt mode. I have never sculpted before, but was wondering what the best method is to fix these odd stretches?

[image]

Comment: I'm not an export, but your topology seems a bit off. Anyway it looks like artifacts from low subdivision. Increase the number of subdivisions in your *SubSruf* modifier

Comment: It looks much better when I use a subsurf modifier but I'm going for a low poly character for a game.

Comment: In that case [baking normal maps from a high poly mesh to a low poly one](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+high+poly+low+poly+bake&tbm=vid) may help

Comment: also try selecting your mesh and pressing ctrl + n, to recalculate your normals. i think your mesh may simply be too low poly, which can make smooth shading look a little off. this shouldn't show up in renders.

Comment: I tried recalculating the normals as well. Unfortunately the oddities still show up when the mesh is exported.